# how to pass the last inserted id in the url in same page

Tags: php, html

```
<h2><a style="margin-left:370px;" class="btnAction" href="<?php echo getResult.php?id=mysqli_insert_id($link)"><span>Click to view results </span></a><br/> <br/> 


<?php 
          if(!empty($_POST))
          { //here post values are inserted
            $userId     = $_SESSION['user_id']; 
            $setId      = $_SESSION['rand_set'];
            $testDate   = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
            $timeSpent  = (!empty($_POST['timeTaken']))?$_POST['timeTaken']:$_SESSION['time']; 
            $userTable  = "user_tests";
            $fields = array("user_id", "set_id", "test_taken", "time_spent", "score", "status");
            $values = array($userId, $setId, $testDate, $timeSpent, $rightAnswer, "1");
            $result = insert($userTable, $fields, $values); 
            $lastId = mysqli_insert_id($link);//want to pass this id in the url
           }
           ?>
```

I'm trying to pass the $lastId that is last inserted id via url, but im not getting the id it's just printed in the url e.g., `(getResult.php?id=mysqli_insert_id($link))`
can anyone help me

Comment: syntaxt issue close ?> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing your `?>` tag in `<a`. and not concatenating string with your last id .

So Change

`href="<?php echo getResult.php?id=mysqli_insert_id($link)"`

to

`href="<?php echo 'getResult.php?id='.mysqli_insert_id($link); ?>"`

Final Code is

```
<h2><a style="margin-left:370px;" class="btnAction" href="<?php echo 'getResult.php?id='.mysqli_insert_id($link); ?>"><span>Click to view results </span></a><br/> <br/>
```

Comment: id is passing as id=0, i think it is sending before an insert, button action and insert operations are in same page

Comment: how you getting `$link`?

Comment: that is in db config file it is a common variable for db connection

Comment: give the link below after the php function

Comment: thnku@urfusion and its working fine now @ arun kumaresh

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php 
              if(!empty($_POST))
              { //here post values are inserted
                $userId     = $_SESSION['user_id']; 
                $setId      = $_SESSION['rand_set'];
                $testDate   = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
                $timeSpent  = (!empty($_POST['timeTaken']))?$_POST['timeTaken']:$_SESSION['time']; 
                $userTable  = "user_tests";
                $fields = array("user_id", "set_id", "test_taken", "time_spent", "score", "status");
                $values = array($userId, $setId, $testDate, $timeSpent, $rightAnswer, "1");
                $result = insert($userTable, $fields, $values); 
                $lastId = mysqli_insert_id($link);//want to pass this id in the url
               }
               ?>


 <h2><a style="margin-left:370px;" class="btnAction" href="<?php echo getResult.php?id='.$lastId'"?><span>Click to view results </span></a><br/> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <h2><a style="margin-left:370px;" class="btnAction" href="<?php echo 'getResult.php?id='.mysqli_insert_id($link); ?>"><span>Click to view results </span></a>
```